# Masking Resource Source URL in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am currently using Laravel as an API to serve content from Azure Blob Storage. My hope was to hide the source URL to my azure resources and create some kind of a temporary path so the end user never has the possibility of seeing an azure url as I'm working with content that needs to be quite secure. This way in serving it through the app I will be able to perform my own authorization and analytic tracking for each resource.

**I'm looking for some guidance or best practises as to how I should accomplish this within php/laravel or other alternatives that could help fix my problem**

*EDIT*

I was hoping to make

myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob.jpg

into

mysite.com/images/renamedblob.jpg

*/EDIT*

Thank you

Comment: Basically, we don't need to do that for security reasons, because Azure Storage provides a comprehensive set of security capabilities which together enable developers to build secure applications. For example, in Blob Storage you can set all of the containers to private and implement the use of an SAS service throughout your applications. You can refer to [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-security-guide) for more info.